# Virtualbox network adapter settings

Tags: networking, virtualbox

linux in the guest OS.

How to configure `virtualbox` to use the default gateway of the host? I'm trying to get IP address of host using terminal in the VM.

When I do a `traceroute`, for example, i have to use `-I` flag to get the information, otherwise the output shows `_gateway`.

When I try changing adapter settings from NAT to any of the other options, the enable network adapter box is grayed out, not available.

I'm VERY new at this so please be patient. Thanks...

Comment: Welcome to the site. While I can understand your desire not to be treated in a condescending way, please note that assuming such behaviour beforehand may make it less likely that contributors invest the time to help you track down the problem. Also, please edit your post to include information on which guest OS you are running inside the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with protocol in this area of StackExchange but I found the answer.
Many people have issues finding the solution to this obstacle.The command is:
ip route add default via *ip address* dev *device name*
You'll have to test it with ifconfig